# Docker builds redis, mounts the host network and uses 192.168.*.* to access the redis server and is denied

Tags: docker, redis, redis-sentinel

Use windows docker to build redis and set bind to 0.0.0.0. Turn off protected mode. In redis-cli, you can only use 127.0.0.1 to access the local redis server. It prompts "Could not connect to Redis at `192.168.*.*:6379`: Connection refused", but I found that using `192.168.*.*` can access those redis-services that use docker virtual network

I hope to use `192.168.*.*` to access redis-service. Because of using redis-sentinel, when using redis-sentinel, the redis host and slave addresses obtained are docker virtual addresses and cannot be accessed in the application.